# Ember.js round the big decimal number

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I need to a help. I am trying to push an ember object in an array and when I push an object then ember convert the big decimal number 999999999999999999.99 to 1000000000000000000.  It round the value if digits are greater than 14.

Here is the code

```
var editableRows = [];
editableRows.pushObject(Ember.Object.create({bigNumber: 999999999999999999.99}));

console.log(editableRows);
Class {bigNumber: 1000000000000000000, __ember1484840094341: null, __ember_meta__: Meta}
```

Is there is any way to prevent this default behavior of ember ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour of javascript (or any language). (Look for IEEE 754 for more).

You should keep two number (scale and precision) or you should use string. 
My suggestion is to use any decimal library (such as: [decimal.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/decimal.js/)).